# Material-table: Is it possible to change filter icon only for single column?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, material-table

I am using material-table in my React project. I set icon for all filter fields in my table:

```
icons={{
    Filter: React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <SearchIcon ref={ref} />),
  }}
```

It is OK but I want to set another icon for one of my column filters because I will use another customized filter with

```
customFilterAndSearch
```

How I can change only this column filter icon?